# How to fix Syntax error, unexpected '' (T_STRING)?

Tags: php, parse-error

The error that I am receiving is this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TokenType' (T_STRING) in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\cs5339\lepichardo\4339_f22_assignment1\TokenType.php on line 2. To be clear, both files are php, and they both are in the same director. The code below is where I include the enum TokenType so that I would be able to use it.

```
<?php
   include 'TokenType.php'
?>
```

The TokenType.php looks like this

```
<?php
   enum TokenType{
      case INT;
      case STRING;
      case COMMA;
   }
?>
```

As far as I now, this should be fine, but gives me that error in that particular line.
If there is any other way to declare and imlpement the enum variable in php I would like to be explained to how to. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enums are only available in PHP 8.1+. The error suggests you are running PHP 7.

Here's some results of running the following code using various PHP versions (using https://3v4l.org/qHU4f)

```
<?php
   enum TokenType{
      case INT;
      case STRING;
      case COMMA;
   }
   echo 'hello world';
```

> Output for 8.1.0 - 8.1.11, 8.2rc1 - rc3
>
> hello world

> Output for 8.0.1 - 8.0.24
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "TokenType" in /in/qHU4f on line 2
>
> Process exited with code 255.

> Output for 7.4.0 - 7.4.32
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TokenType' (T_STRING) in /in/qHU4f on line 2
>
> Process exited with code 255.

As you can see by the last result, `unexpected 'TokenType' (T_STRING)` is an error you would receive in PHP 7